# How to create action for HtmlCommandLink#setActionExpression()

Tags: jsf-2

I am trying to add commandlink programatically, but I am not able to add action.

```
HtmlCommandLink link = new HtmlCommandLink();
link.setValue(data);
link.setActionExpression(no idea);
```

How do I create it?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`ExpressionFactory#createMethodExpression()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ExpressionFactory.html#createMethodExpression%28javax.el.ELContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class%5B%5D%29).

Here's a convenience method:

```
private static MethodExpression createMethodExpression(String expression, Class<?> returnType) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(
        context.getELContext(), expression, returnType, new Class[0]);
}
```

Here's how you could use it, provided that you've a `public String doSomething() {}` action in a managed bean identified by `#{bean}`:

```
link.setActionExpression(createMethodExpression("#{bean.doSomething}", String.class));
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the help.. but its not working, it stays on the same page. i actually want to redirect to other page using this action method. pls suggest me if there are any other option

Comment: That's a different problem and does absolutely not require "any other option". First, have you given the component a fixed ID? E.g. `link.setId("foo")`.

Comment: Thanks.. it worked. But the problem is its not navigating to other page.